# SearchView does not show suggestions

Tags: android, kotlin, searchview

So I want to show a suggestion in a `searchView` which is now inside a toolbar. So I created this adapter and it doesn't seem to work and the app is also crashing with this error `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

**Adapter**

```
class SearchHitchAdapter(context: Context, cursor: Cursor) : CursorAdapter(context, cursor, false) {

    private val dataSet = arrayListOf<String>(*context.resources.getStringArray(R.array.city_states))

    override fun newView(context: Context?, cursor: Cursor?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val inflater = context!!.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        return inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false)
    }

    override fun bindView(view: View?, context: Context?, cursor: Cursor?) {
        val position = cursor!!.position
        val textView = view!!.findViewById(android.R.id.text1) as TextView
        textView.text = dataSet[position]
    }
}
```

This function is being called inside `onQueryTextChange`

```
 private fun setUpSearchSuggestions(query: String) {

        val dataSet = getCityList()

        val columns = arrayOf("_id", "text")
        val temp = arrayOf(0, "default")
        val cursor = MatrixCursor(columns)

        for (i in 0 until dataSet.size) {

            val city = dataSet[i]

            if (city.toLowerCase(Locale.US).contains(query.toLowerCase(Locale.US))) {
                temp[0] = i
                temp[1] = city[i]
                cursor.addRow(temp)
            }
        }
        searchVIew.suggestionsAdapter = SearchAdapter(context!!, cursor)
    }
```

This is not working can somebody help me or suggest me something.

Answer (score 1):

This line in your code looks suspicious:

> ```
> temp[1] = city[i]
> ```

This is the same as writing `temp[i] = city.get(i)`: you are trying to get the character from `city` at position `i`.

Since `i` is the loop variable, and you're looping over `dataset`, this is very likely a mistake. There's no guarantee that every string in the data set is as long as the data set itself. Imagine that you have a list of a thousand cities; chances are very good that each city's name is less than one thousand characters long.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the error at the same exact line. But why I don't understand. What code is doing if it contains the string then add to the cursor. If I'm doing this `temp[1] = city` then all the list shows in the suggestion.

Comment: Well, what it's doing now is adding the `i`-th character of the city name to the cursor. If you just use `city` instead, then it adds the city name to the cursor.

Answer (score -1):

The exception "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException" says that you are accessing the data which doesn't exists. Check if your dataset has the right list.